# transformerFactory.newTransformer getting slower during tests

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem where I do not know what the root cause actually is.

I create an instance of javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory and directly afterwards I parse a xsltSource:

```
protected synchronized Transformer getTransformer(Source xsltSource)
    throws TransformerConfigurationException {

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource); 
    return transformer;
}
```

Now I have a test that is part of the test suite. When I run that test standalone the code above takes around 1ms constantly.

When I run that test as part of my test suite it takes longer. This happens as well in eclipse as with gradle.
The duration rises linear with the amount of tests that run before.

Its orders of magnitudes slower, like 10 - 1000 times, depending on how much tests run before that specific test.

Using a cached instance of the TransfomerFactory will cut the time the test takes in half. But the symptom remains the same.
I have been profiling it, but dont see anything suspicious, except the the test takes longer.

Any ideas what might be the cause here?

**Edit** I am using the *com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl*
*com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl*
classes.
Which are the ones provided by the JDK, I guess.

**Edit2** I had the assumption it had something to do with the number of classes loaded (which is one thing that changes during the test runs). And therefore loaded classes arbitrarily for the single tests, but it did not change the timing. So the number of classes loaded seems not to be at fault here.

**Edit3** I added the saxon parser to my classpath and referred that one specifically:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);    
TransformerImpl transformer = (TransformerImpl) transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
```

The behaviour is still the same, the test standalone runs fast, but as part of the test suite it is much slower.

**Edit4** I have the same behaviour with this line of code:

```
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
```

It becomes slower, the more tests run before that specific test, but does not if it is executed standalone.

Comment: what actual xml transformer are you using? the built in one? xalan? saxon? etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>After two days of digging it turns out that xalan takes more and more time the more paths are on the classpath.
It uses the sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration class to traverse through it, looking for an implementation of the SaxParserFactory, which takes longer and longer, the more of our tests are running, because they fill up the classpath and the classloader has to search through more classes.</del>

Actually, in the last days I figured out what our problems really were.

In our algorithm we
1. Created a new instance of the TemplateFactory very often
2. Created a new instance of the SAXParserFactory very often
3. Did not cache a template that we recompiled very often too, while
it was the same.

So the solution was to create one instance of the TemplateFactory and
the SAXParserfactory, make sure they dont run multithreaded and pass
them down the call chain, as well as caching our one template and
reusing that.

Last but not least, I figured out that there is a chain that the JDK
uses to look for an implementation of the TemplateFactory and
SAXParserFactory using the ServiceLoader. Which took a really long
time in eclipse, as somehow the places, where the ServiceLoader looks
for implementations got filled up over time (you can read that in the
docs of the ServiceLoader, where this actually happens).
Passing a system property for the default implementations of these
interfaces will fix that too.

All in all our performance was improved by over 90% :-)

**Edit** As requested, I will not add the property itself, but a link to the javadoc, that explains exactly what happens and what you have to do:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()

These are the properties *javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory* and *javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory* but, what you set it to, depends on which JDK and / or parser library you use.

Comment: For completeness can you add where and how you set the system property?